# How to disable Babel Unicode compilation?

Tags: javascript, unicode, ecmascript-6, babeljs, unicode-string

If you have an input code like:

```
var x = "\u0000";
```

it will be converted to

```
"use strict";

var x = "\0";
```

You can test this on the Babel website itself: **[Example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=var%20x%20%3D%20%22%5Cu0000%22%3B)**

What is necessary to disable Unicode compilation?

*(Tested with Babel 6.19.0)*

Answer (score 2):

`"\u0000"` Is a specific example, it will not happen with other unicode chars.

If you try it with `\u0200` for example - it will not change.

You can see in the following example that the actual value is exactly the same:

```js
console.log('\u0000' === '\0')
```

Comment: You're right, with `\u0200` it works. But take the Unicode equivalent of `A` as another example, it will be [converted too](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=var%20x%20%3D%20%22%5Cu0000%22%3B%0Avar%20y%20%3D%20%22%5Cu0200%22%3B%0Avar%20a%20%3D%20%22%5Cu0041%22%3B). Also, regarding my question: Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can, the question is - why do you need to change it? The actual value is exactly the same.

Comment: I'm adding this character for a later replacement. It's safer to use the Unicode equivalent instead of the compiled character.

Comment: The value is exactly the same so I'm not sure what does it matter. Is almost like to use `var a = 2+2` instead of `var a = 4`.

Comment: You don't need to understand why I'd like to do so, SO is about answers and this doesn't answer >What is necessary to disable Unicode compilation?<?

Comment: Furthermore the sentence that it doesn't happen with other Unicode characters is wrong (see my comment above).

Comment: In the end - you are here because you need help. The language you use ("you don't need to understand...") doesn't really encourage people to help . Sometimes - if you provide more information, it will help understand better what you are looking for and give a better answer. Regarding your comment = same with the `\u0200` it's equal to `A`. You can check it.